# variable assignment is not allowed in a cursor declaration

Tags: sql, cursor

I am trying to use cursor in SQL and getting "variable assignment is not allowed in a cursor declaration." & "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'
" error. Following is my query :

```
 DECLARE @descriptor NVARCHAR(420)
 DECLARE cur_descriptor CURSOR 
 STATIC FOR
   SELECT @descriptor = descriptor FROM (SELECT * from IX_Mesh WHERE terms = 'tumors') as CHILD
   SELECT Terms FROM IX_Mesh WHERE descriptor = @descriptor  

   OPEN cur_descriptor
   FETCH NEXT
      FROM cur_descriptor INTO @descriptor
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

      BEGIN 
       PRINT @descriptor
       FETCH NEXT 
         FROM cur_descriptor INTO @descriptor
     END
 CLOSE cur_descriptor
 DEALLOCATE cur_descriptor
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is hard about the error message?  This is the cursor declaration:

```
DECLARE cur_descriptor CURSOR STATIC FOR
   SELECT @descriptor = descriptor
----------^
   FROM (SELECT * from IX_Mesh WHERE terms = 'tumors') as CHILD
```

That assignment is a no-no.  Just do:

```
DECLARE cur_descriptor CURSOR STATIC FOR
   SELECT descriptor
   FROM (SELECT * from IX_Mesh WHERE terms = 'tumors') as CHILD;
```

Or, better yet:

```
DECLARE cur_descriptor CURSOR STATIC FOR
   SELECT descriptor from IX_Mesh WHERE terms = 'tumors';
```

Comment: I've two select statements. In one I am storing the result in assigned variable and in second query I am using that variable.

Comment: I've two select statements. In one I am storing the result in assigned variable and in second query I am using that variable.                    The above query gives me the result but how can I utilize that in my second query???

Comment: @user3771772 . . . Do you understand how cursors work?  The SQL doesn't return results until you do a `FETCH NEXT`.  You are not using the `TERMS` anyway, so that is totally unnecessary.  Unless you want the stored procedure to print out those results, in which case it should be after the `FETCH`.

Comment: Actually I am new to cursor and this the first time I am using it.  All terms are associated with descriptor,basically what I want to achieve is when the first query returns any result then I want to use that in second one? Any suggestions..?

Comment: @user3771772 . . . Yes.  Put the second statement after the `fetch next`.  That is when you get the value from the query.